# Sequelize can't make 'belongsto' and 'hasmany' association

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a 'comment' model as following

```
var comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    author_openid:{
        type:  DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    text: { type:DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull:false }
});
model.sync();
```

a 'user' model as following

```
var model = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    openid: { 
        type:  DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
model.sync();
```

Then association as following

```
comment.belongsTo( user, { foreignKey:"author_openid", targetKey:"openid" } )
user.hasMany( comment, { foreignKey:"author_openid", sourceKey:"openid" } )
```

I want make an association between 'user' and 'comment' as above and do a query as following

```
user.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: comment
    }],
    raw: true
})
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it running any query and you're not getting the expected results? No results?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are defining `author_openid` and `openid` as `STRING` where should be `INTEGER`

Comment: They're both defined as strings, so that should be valid. We still don't know what the op meant by `wrong`. Is there an error? All this code could be fine, but maybe op isn't resolving the promise from the `findAll` :shrug:

Comment: Thanks all, I removed related tables from MySql, then run the codes and it goes well now,  the problem is MySql has had wrong attributes or association before model definition.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#eager-loading), make it seem like your include should just be an array with the model not an object.

```
const users = await user.findAll({
  include: [ comment ],
  raw: true
})
```